White splash screen on tablet Android Xamarin
when oppening app on tablet lenovo tab m10 Android 12, app showing white splash screen, but if I open from playmarket it is normal splash screen, it is specific problem for only this table, on other devices all works normally
styles.xml light
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#00adef</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00adef</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#00adef</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#00adef</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">#ffffff</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
  <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">#ffffff</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent="MyTheme">
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/lock_icon</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage">@drawable/brand_icon</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#00FFFFFF</item>
  </style>
</resources>

styles.xml dark
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#00adef</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00adef</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#00adef</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#00adef</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">@color/black</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  </style>
  <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">#ffffff</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent="MyTheme">
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/lock_icon_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage">@drawable/brand_icon_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#00FFFFFF</item>
  </style>
</resources>

splashscreen.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f2f2f2"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/splash_image"/>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="85dp">
        <bitmap
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/brand_icon"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>

SplashScreen.cs
[Activity(MainLauncher = true,
        NoHistory = true,
        Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash",
        Exported = true)]
    public class SplashScreen : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

            if (Intent?.Extras != null)
            {
                intent.PutExtras(Intent.Extras);
            }
            
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }

I tired adding
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
but it dont really work
also if I am changing color in
<item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
it also change color
